# Rspec not showing the updates on a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

Here is my Rspec when testing an API end point related to Users:

```
 context "updating a user" do
    let(:user) { User.create! }

    it "should let me update a user without an email" do
      put "/api/v1/users/#{user.id}", {:user => {:first_name => 'Willy'}}.to_json, {'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => "Token token=\"#{auth_token.access_token}\""}
      p user.inspect
    end
```

And the controller action that I am testing looks like this:

```
def update
    begin
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        p @user.inspect
        render json: @user, :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
      else
        render json: { :errors => @user.errors }, :status => :unprocessable_entity
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      head :not_found
    end
  end
```

Surprisingly, the @user.inspect in the controller shows this:

```
"#<User id: 2, first_name: \"Willy\", last_name: nil, email: nil, state: nil, created_at: \"2013-06-22 11:21:22\", updated_at: \"2013-06-22 11:21:22\">"
```

And the user.inspect in the rspec, right after the call to the controller has been done, looks like this:

```
"#<User id: 2, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: nil, state: nil, created_at: \"2013-06-22 11:21:22\", updated_at: \"2013-06-22 11:21:22\">"
```

Why does the Rspec not catch the updates? I mean, I have tested this manually and the database gets updated correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe try reloading your user object by calling `#reload` on it.

Comment: WOW! That solved it. Can you explain further why is that needed??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rspec example you define `user` method with `let`, which returns ActiveRecord object. Your controller is creating different object, that points to the same database entry. Change in db is not reflected in `user` object in rspec example, as there is no callback mechanism that would notify it to change.

Using `#reload` method on AR object in test should solve your problem, as it forces reloading data from db.

Comment: Nice answer samuil. Wanted to add a blog post of mine which explains the solution more thoroughly - you can read it here: http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/activerecord-and-in-memory-object-state/